# How to take the sum of a range of cells up to a certain total

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

So, I am not quite sure how to ask this and it is my first question on this site but I will do my best.

In my line of work I am given a very large data sheet containing the amount of hours worked of hundreds of employees.

My task is to go through this data sheet and look specifically at the amount of hours that a certain employee has worked and determine a couple things.

First, is if the amount of hours they worked is equal to or over 48 hours in order to classify the hours that go over the 48 hour line as overtime hours to be billed at a higher rate.

If the sum of the hours is under 48 then obviously nothing needs to be done. Where the problem comes is that the way we receive our data is a little wonky.

I have whipped up a very simplified sample of what I work with and you'll notice that there is a point where one of the shifts is billed at a "composite rate" whatever program we use to log hours recognizes that the amount of hours for that shift has exceeded 48 and bills the hours before it crosses 48 at the regular rate and whatever hours remain at an overtime rate (regular rate * 1.5)

So, my question is: Is there a way I can write a program to scan through these shifts per employee and it can recognize how many hours to take from the "composite" amount and split that into hours that are billed at a regular rate and hours billed at an overtime rate. I have attached a screenshot of what I start with and what I want to end with.

Thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSexd.png)

Comment: I understand this data sheet will contain hundreds of names. Will a single sheet contain more than one week's worth of hours? If so, what day of the week is Day 1?

Comment: The problem is it is not exactly the same for every employee, not every one of them works every day of the week but the dates shouldn't be any sooner than the 20th and any later than the 26th. Obviously there will be some outliers but those can be manually dealt with.

Comment: I know you said you wanted to insert a new row for the "composite" day, where one row would be for regular rate and another row would be for OT. Is this critical or is it satisfactory to split Regular Rate and OT Rate into different columns but keeping all the same rows?

Comment: Definitely helpful although not exactly what I am looking for. While it is not necessarily critical for the solution to create a new row, that is how I will have to format it in the end. Additionally, these are working hours taken from a specific week so the range of days usually does not stray outside of the range I gave in the comment above.

Comment: Fair enough. AFAIK a formula cannot insert a row, so you will need a VBA answer or some other answer. Out of my league. Best of luck.

Comment: Not a problem, I appreciate your help. I am fairly certain I can work with what you have given me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you wanted to insert a new row for the "composite" day, where one row would be for regular rate and another row would be for OT. If this is critical, then this is not the answer for you. But at least you will be able to identify composite days as well as pre- and post- composite days.

First, it's critical that you have this table sorted by employee and then by date. Despite your answer in the comments, I assumed you have a single chart with lots of employees and more than one week's worth of data.

You provided Columns A through D.

```
Column E: blank

Column F: "Week" =WEEKNUM(B2+1)

Column G: "New Person New Week Row Num" =IF(AND(A2=A1,F2=F1),G1,ROW())

Column H: "Running Total Per Person Per Week" =SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(G2,4)):D2)

Column I: "Regular Rate" =IF(H2<48,D2,D2-J2)

Column J: "OT Rate" =IF(AND(G2=G1,H1>48),D2,IF(H2>48,H2-48,0))
```

Column F: "Week" simply tells us what week of the year we're dealing with. The data you provided started on a Saturday (which is weird) so that's why it has "+1+ in it.

Column G: "New Person New Week Row Num" basically tells Excel when a new person and/or a new week begins, so that we restart our running count of hours at the start of each new week or when we are dealing with a new employee.

Column H: "Running Total Per Person Per Week" relies on Column G and will tally a running total of hours for that person during that week.

Column I: "Regular Rate" says that if the total hours worked so far is less then 48, then the entirety of that day's work is Regular Rate, but if the total hours worked so far is more than 48, then only tally up that portion of the day's work which is not attributable to OT.

Column J: "OT Rate" Says, if we are still dealing with the same person in the same week, and if this person went into OT on the day before (Cell J2 is looking at cell H1), then the entirety of today's hours must also be OT, otherwise, take the hours worked so far and subtract 48, and that amount is composite OT for today.

[image: my terrible idea that doesn't add new rows like you asked]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).